# SIMPLEST way to set up password protection for a static site, with basic admin UI?

Tags: htaccess, security, authentication, password

I have a static site.

I would like the simplest approach to password protecting a directory, with a basic admin UI for adding/removing users. I will have so few users that I don't care about performance.

I don't care if it's PHP or Django or whatever, I just want a complete software package.

- Apache basic auth isn't good, because you can't log out. Nor is there a UI for adding users.
- I tried throwing everything behind Django auth and serving the files through Django. However, Chrome treats all my text/css headers as text/plain, so I don't get any stylesheets showing.
- I can't use mod_xsendfile on my server because I can't reconfigure Apache to add new modules. I think this approach is overkill anyway.
- I can try configuring Nginx's X-Accel-Redirect, however that requires implementing all the Django code for auth myself, and I'd prefer an existing solution. However, this is my backup plan.

Is there a code package that implements authentication with basic admin for a static site?

Comment: Have you tried WordPress then adding your pages into the blogging system?

Comment: [directorypass](http://www.directorypass.com/) might be what your looking for. Unfortunately it still uses Apache's basic auth, so no logout.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do to handle authentication even if it is a static site will still become somewhat dynamic simply from the need to have a database backend for authentication, which in turn means more than likely the trade-off of using the database to power the page content as well. What would best suit your needs here is a content management system. There are a large number of them out there and the vast majority of them have user authentication built in. This has the advantage of providing a logout experience for the end user as well as being a pre-canned solution that has been tested and undergoes maintenance.

Some of the PHP-based solutions that I can think of would be...

- [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/) - [Authentication Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/User_Group_Access_levels_explained_in_simple_terms)
- [WordPress](https://wordpress.com/) - [Authentication Documentation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/user-login)
- [Plone](https://plone.org/) - [Authentication Documentation](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/config/users-groups.html)